# Firestorm needs 32-bits libs, which seem, unavailable

Tags: package-management, software-installation

The following, should illustrate my predicament:

Output:

```
yogich@yogich-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/firestorm$ ./firestorm
64-bit Linux detected.
Multi-arch support detected for i386.
Multi-arch support detected for amd64.
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:/usr/lib64/dri:/usr/lib32/dri:/usr/lib/dri
Running from /home/yogich/firestorm
```

How else, to run? Desktop symlink, no joy; run from file manager, no joy.

```
./firestorm: line 179: bin/do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin: No such file or directory 
*** Bad shutdown ($LL_RUN_ERR). ***

You are running the Firestorm Viewer on a x86_64 platform.  The
most common problems when launching the Viewer (particularly
'bin/do-not-directly-run-firestorm-bin: not found' and 'error while
loading shared libraries') may be solved by installing your Linux
distribution's 32-bit compatibility packages.
For example, on Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linuxes you might run:
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl
```

Therefore, I copy/paste command line:

```
yogich@yogich-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~/firestorm$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-kde ia32-libs-sdl
[sudo] password for yogich: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
```

Voila:

```
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-gtk
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-kde
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-sdl</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install 32-bit libraries from an old repository. **Note that this is a bad way of doing it and may cause undesirable effect sometimes** but is suggested in [firestorm](http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/32-bit_firestorm_in_64-bit_ubuntu) wiki. You can either do a full 32-bit install or only install the needed 32-bit libraries

**Full 32-bit install**

This method installs the 32-bit libraries from a previous distribution

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once everything is working, it is better to remove the `ia32-libs-raring.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and do `sudo apt-get update`.

There is also an option to install only the needed 32-bit libraries as given in the [wiki](http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/32-bit_firestorm_in_64-bit_ubuntu) if you do not want to do a full 32-bit install.

**Install only the needed 32-bit libraries**

Ensure 32-bit architecture support is enabled:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Install base libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386
```

Install gstreamer0.10 libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg:i386 gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:i386
```

You might also have to install `esound-common`, `libao-common`,`libao4` `pulseaudio-esound-compat` depending on your system.

You should also try installing following packages if you are running into problems running Firestorm. Note that some of the packages mentioned in the code below may have been already installed as a part of other packages you installed by running codes above. Also **note** that `libstdc++` will try to **remove some packages installed in your system**, so **read carefully** what it is going to uninstalled before pressing enter!

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-pic:i386 
sudo apt-get install libapr1:i386 libaprutil1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty:i386 
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libuuid1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrender1:i386
```

Consult the [wiki](http://wiki.phoenixviewer.com/32-bit_firestorm_in_64-bit_ubuntu) for more information.